# What is the probability that Miss Lear wins exactly 3 of these matches?

Tags: probability

Miss Lear plays Miss Gill at chess.  The probability that Miss Lear wins a match is 0.6. Miss Lear and Miss Gill play $5$ matches against each other. What is the probability that Miss Lear wins exactly $3$ of these matches?

I make the answer to be $0.6^3 = 0.216$.

or should it be $0.6^3\times0.4^2$?

Comment: Both answers are wrong. In how many ways can Miss Lear win 3 games? She can win games 1,2,3 or 1,2,4 or 1,2,5... or 3,4,5. There are ${5 \choose 3}$ different arrangements of wins and losses. The probability for each arrangement is $0.6^3 \times 0.4^2$. So the answer is...

Answer (score 2):

The first answer, $0.6^3$, is the probability that Lear wins the *first three* matches. And it's the probability that she wins the last three matches. For any subset $\{i,j,k\}\subseteq\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, $0.6^3$ is the probability that Lear wins matches $i,j$ and $k$ (with no limits on what happens on the rest of the matches). So this is not the right answer.

The second answer, $0.6^30.4^2$, is the probability that Lear wins the *first three* matches **and** loses the second two matches. This is closer, but you are still not quite there, because Lear might also win matches number $2,3,5$ and lose matches $1$ and $4$. So again, this is not the right answer.

---

To get the right answer, you need to modify your second result. Think about all the possibilities in which Lear wins exactly three matches. How many are there? What are their probabilities?

Comment: Sorry, I don't completely follow, could you explain what the correct answer is?

Comment: @ParmjitNar This is a site that encourages and helps with *learning*. The point here is that you get *help* finding a solution, rather than having a solution handed to you. I helped you by telling you what you did was wrong, and why it was wrong, and even told you what it is that you actually calculated. Knowing that, I also gave you some guidelines to continue. Now, it's your job to actually try to solve the problem again.

Comment: (53).(0.6)3×(0.4)2

Comment: @ParmjitNar Where did you get the $53$?

Comment: @ParmjitNar Why do you think it should be $\frac53$?